Question regarding integral mean value theorem
I am sorry for cross-posting a question that I asked on mathoverflow. It is about the integral form of the mean value theorem which states that for the range $[a,b]$  for two continuous functions $f$ and $g$ the relation holds
\begin{equation}
I = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) dx = f(c)\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx = f(c)\,G\, \quad c\in (a,b)\,.
\end{equation}
I am looking for methods that allow to compute i) the point $c$ or ii) directly the value $f(c)$ without explicitly computing $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) dx$. I understand that I am asking how to compute $I=f(c)G$ without using $I$ and $f(c)$, still I believe that some work must have been done in this field.
The functions I consider satisfy $f>0,g>0\,\forall x$
I would be happy if you could point me to some related work. Maybe you are also familiar how to tackle my problem if more restrictions on $f$ and/or $g$ are considered. Thank you for your help.
